# How to click on dropdown list items through Selenium in VBA macro?

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a macro to download a file from a web page. I have coded the login and navigating to main download page however, unable to get codes to click on a drop-down menu on a web page. I need to click on 3 dots then click on `Download xlsx` to start downloading the file. I can not proceed to rest of the codes until file is downloaded. Here is the link to HTML properties of this dropdownlist

```
obj.FindElementsByClass("ant-dropdown-menu-item").Click
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Sorry Kira I was stil editing my question. Please repost your edits.

Comment: I think you need to use `.FindElementByClass().AsSelect.SelectByValue <value here>` method. And you shouldn't be using `Elements` with the `s`, you only want the single element you're after. `AsSelect` indicates you are using a dropdown.

Comment: Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html so we can test

Comment: We need to see the select and options html and the html for the ... and the file download html. Ideally, supply the url.

Comment: It's an internal company portal with no access to outsiders. I've taken a screenshot of the html properties and the buttons i want to click. Here is the image link [Imgur Image link](https://i.imgur.com/tP5vbow.png)

Comment: Please use snippet tool via [edit] to insert html. Screenshots are not very useful for testing,

Comment: I tried to insert html but the formatting is completely deteriorated. So it's unusable. It's an internal portal and needs to be connected to internal server to work properly. Sorry I can can not help with this. Is there any way to click on Download XLSX lable as shown in the screenshot? Direct file link is not working either.

Comment: inserting html is going via snippet tool and paste in top left of 4 boxes that appear. Click [edit] to find editing tools and look for icon that resembles a document with  <> on it. If HTML has issue use an [html formatter](https://htmlformatter.com/) first.  You don't need the entire page html. If you wish to share large html sections use https://pastebin.com/ and then share the link.

Comment: Is ```obj.FindElementByXPath ("//span[contains(text(),'Download XLSX')]")``` code correct? I found this xpath using ChroPath extension form chrome to click that dropdown menu itme. However I am getting NoSuchElementerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had figured out the solution. I had to click on the blank space to get that drop down buttons appear. Then clicked as usually. I got the element path form Chropath chrome add on  and used xpath.

```
Obj.FindElementByClass("insight__header").Click         '-----------This clicks on blank space to show 3 dots.
Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/header[1]/span[2]/div[1]/button[1]/i[1]/*").Click   '---------This cicks on 3 dots and displays the menu.
Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[4]/span[1]").Click    '---------This clicks on Download xlxs button to start downloading the file.
```